# How to add multiple drops downs to Google Apps Form created dynamically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am a new to Google Apps Script programming. I am trying to use a Google sheet to dynamically populate a Google Form. I have one drop down working, but when I try to add a second it just duplicates the first.

Here is my code:

```
//bonus, gets values from spreadsheet and returns them
function getValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow);

  var range_team = sheet.getRange(1, 4, lastRow);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var values_team = range_team.getValues();

  return values;
  return values_team;
}

//what you'll need to call initially to create the form, and store id in project properties
function createForm() {

// create Form 
 var form = FormApp.create('Test Form 11_6_14_3');

// first drop down list
  var values_team = getValues(1,4,3,4);
  var list_team = form.addListItem();
  var listItems_team = list_team.setChoiceValues(values_team);

// second drop down list  

  var values = getValues(1,1,1,18);
  var list = form.addListItem();
  var listItems = list.setChoiceValues(values);

  var formId = form.getId();

  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('Test Form 11_6_14_3', formId);
}
```

Thanks and be gentle...remember I'm a noob...

Answer (score 0):

1. You should check your code at `return values; return values_team;` Do you think second return statement ever going to execute? It will never execute.
2. Why are you passing values in `getValues()` while you haven't defined any parameters in `getValues()` function. There is no use of these values in your `getValues()` function.
3. Why don't you use `getRange()` in following way to make it work. This will give you the result as you want.

   ```
   function getValues(x,y) {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
     var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
     var range = sheet.getRange(x, y, lastRow);
     var values = range.getValues();

     return values;
     //return values_team;                  // remove this as there it won't be called ever
   }

   function createForm() {

     // create Form 
     var form = FormApp.create('Test Form 11_6_14_3');

     // first drop down list
     var values_team = getValues(1,1);   // add your range values here as a parameter
     var list_team = form.addListItem();
     var listItems_team = list_team.setChoiceValues(values_team);

     // second drop down list  

     var values = getValues(1,4);        // add your range values here as a parameter
     var list = form.addListItem();
     var listItems = list.setChoiceValues(values);

     var formId = form.getId();

     PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('Test Form 11_6_14_3', formId);
   }
   ```